# Proving $(1-4 x) f^{\prime}(x)=2 f(x)$ with power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider $$\begin{array}{c} 
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 n) !}{(n !)^{2}} x^{n}, \quad \text { for } \left.x \in\right]-R, R[. \\
f^{\prime}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2 n) !}{(n !)^{2}} n x^{n-1}, \quad \text { for } \left.x \in\right]-R, R[
\end{array}$$

**Prove that: $$(1-4 x) f^{\prime}(x)=2 f(x) \text { for } \left.x \in\right]-R, R[$$**

$R$ is the radius of convergence. If calculated correctly: $R=1/4$

---

I'm really stuck with this problem. I tried to multiply in $1-4x$ into the sum. But I just can't see how I should manipulate the sum. Is there another and easier way of showing it?

Comment: Just change the index of summation in $f'(x) $ to start with $n=0$ and the problem becomes as trivial as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Try collecting powers and equating coefficients. On the right, you have
$$
2f(x) =2\left( 1+ 2 x + 6 x^2 +20x^3 +70x^4+\cdots\right)
$$On the left, you have
$$
(1-4x)f'(x) = (1-4x)\left(2+12x+60x^2+280x^3+1260x^4+\cdots\right)
$$Can you collect terms and show the coefficients on both sides have to match?